# Problem with jQuery dynamically calling functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for(n=0;n < 20;n++){
     $('#button' + n).click(function () { newAction(n); });
}

function newAction(x){
     alert(x);
}
```

The problem with this code is that when I press buttons their click actions somehow are not linked to their number, so by pressing button5 i may get alert 6 or something like that.

Comment: Is it predictable or are the alerts random ?

Comment: If you could post a chunk of the HTML you're using this on, it would also help.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This looks weird but this would be more appropriate way to create the closure so you can access the loop-scope variable per iteration...

```
  for(var n = 0; n < 20; n++) {
    $('#button' + n).click((function(i) {
      return function(e) { newAction(i) }
    })(n));
  }

  function newAction(x){
    alert(x);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

[Mr Lucky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690736/problem-with-jquery-dynamically-calling-functions/690815#690815) is on the right track, but his example I found a bit hard to read.

```
function button_bind( num ){ 
     $("#button" + num ).click(function(){
         newAction(num);
     });
}

for(var n = 0; n < 20; n++) {
     button_bind(n);
}

function newAction(x){
     alert(x);
}
```

This should clear up your scoping issue.

The above could be transformed to inline:

```
for(var n = 0; n < 20; n++) {

     (function(num){ 

        $("#button" + num ).click(function(){
         newAction(num);
        });

     })(n);

}

function newAction(x){
     alert(x);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
for(n=0;n < 20;n++){
     $('#button' + n).click(function (n) { newAction(n); });
}

function newAction(x){
     alert(x);
}
```

The reason is closures. When you don't pass the n along with the anonymous function, javascript looks for the variable in its own scope, and the parent scope. The parent scope has an 'n', but this n is the value of the n after the for loop. By passing along the n, you create a new n inside the scope of the function, and this one isn't changed when the for loop runs.

Comment: jQuery sends the first argument of click(function(e) {...});
That would be the event object, not his userdefined variable.

Answer (score -1):

i can think of easier ways to do what you are trying, but this'll work for you:

EDIT: Sorry i thought it was clear i was supplying a replacement for the line inside your loop. Here the entire functioning program

EDIT 2: Okay here's the outer $(document).ready() wrapper also that isn't even in the original question. This has been tested. this works. Even on 1.3+ .. It's the best answer given.

I've put up a functioning version of this program you can try out by [**visiting here**](http://enjoy3d.com/690736.html)

```
$(function() {
  for (n = 0; n < 20; n++){
    $('#button' + n).bind('click', n, function (e) { newAction(e.data); });
  }

});

function newAction(x){
  alert(x);
}
```

Comment: Are you missing something? This does not work for me using the 1.3x jQuery?

Comment: Even your edit would not work, the jQuery docs say you can pass the data that way.  But it's not working if you wire this up in a real page and try it.

Comment: like i said in the edit, I thot it was obvious the one line i supplied went inside the FOR loop. The answer i've given works fine with 1.3.2. Dont quite understand the downvotes, since I think it's the best answer on this page so far

Comment: i wired up a real page and i really tried it and it really works. I assume you understand this all goes inside a $(document).ready() which even the original post didn't have?

Comment: you should use jQuery(function($){ }); to maximise effectiveness. Voted up because the 3-arg-bind does work, as per documented.

Comment: i am learning slowly that partial answers devoid of extra garnishment and frills do not gain you cred at SO. Of course I agree with your comment Kent, just wanted to get the correct answer up and be done with this :)